# Twig asset with CDN using Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

For performance reasons, I want to deliver some of my files from a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Is it possible to configure the "asset" helper such that it automaticly sets something like "static1.xxxx.com/css/main.css" and "static2.xxxx.com/css/main.css"?

Perhaps something like:

```
{{ asset('css/main.css',static1) }}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in in config.yml just add something like:

```
framework:
    templating:
      engines: ['twig']
      assets_base_urls:
        http: [http://yourcdn.com]
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. And how can i use it in twig? Do you have an example?

Comment: In twig then you can just say {{ asset('myasset.css') }}

Comment: besides what @User1191081 remarks 
How Can I use multile CDN, let say I have a CDN per Client. And the client wants to uploas assets to his CDN... Bu mt templates must create valid links.

Comment: `Unrecognized option "assets_base_urls" under "framework.templating". Available options are "cache", "enabled", "engines", "form", "hinclude_default_template", "loaders".`

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to do something like:

```
templating:
    packages:
        cdn:
            base_urls:
                ssl: ['url']
                http: ['url']
```

That way you can do things like asset('yourfile', 'cdn') and also have multiple cdns (by specifying more packages).