# Symfony2 / Twig : Generate Alternate Absolute URL Path for use with CDN?

Tags: php, symfony, cdn, twig

This [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358470/twig-asset-with-cdn-using-symfony-2) almost answers my question. But I want to generate CDN urls in `Twig` to more than just resources. I'd like to generate them for dynamic content. So I don't think an Assetic tweak is the right area to be looking.

For now, I can set CDN_url in `parameters.ini` and use that in my urls. My code would look like this : `{{CDN_Url}}{{url('route',{'param1':'value'}}` .. Code maintenance is one major reason I don't like this option. Then you could do things like check the route for `/cdn/` to generate the CDN url and everything else to be based on the domain. I wouldn't have to run around changing a lot of variables. AND if I wanted to stop the CDN url from generating. I could just modify the route. So there's a lot of benefits to figuring out if there's a clean solution to this.

If, there's not a solution already - how would I start to extend the `{{ url() }}` functionality so that I could use it like `path` and `url`.

Comment: Do you have multi domain site built on symfony2 or have content on CDN that have dynamic url which is defined by symfony routes?

Comment: The way the CDN works is like having a multi-domain. cdn.domain.com/route mirrors my.domain.com/route .. using Pull Origin. SO sometimes, there's good reasons to load the my.domain and other times, like with media, it makes sense to load the cdn.domain.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it with the help of the question you linked by following way

```
{{ asset(path('route',{'param1':'value'})) }}
```

If you need to handle multiple CDN domains you can do it by following way

In `app/config.yml`

```
# app/config.yml
#....
templating:       
  engines: ['twig'] 
  packages:
    cdn1:
      base_urls: ["http://cdn1.domain.com"]
    cdn2:
      base_urls: ["http://cdn2.domain.com"]
```

And then in your twig template file

```
{{ asset('path/of/file', 'cdn1')
```

OR

```
{{ asset('path/of/file', 'cdn2')
```

Comment: This works right out of the box. @Cerad 's solution is great for getting you started on making a little cleaner function all.

Comment: In Symfony 3.0, 'packages' should be nested under `framework:` -> `assets:`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the CDN stuff but as far as extending the url function, take a look at:

Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension

```
public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $generator)
{
    $this->generator = $generator;
}
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'url'  => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getUrl'),
        'path' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getPath'),
    );
}
public function getPath($name, $parameters = array())
{
    return $this->generator->generate($name, $parameters, false);
}

public function getUrl($name, $parameters = array())
{
    return $this->generator->generate($name, $parameters, true);
}
```

So you could get at getUrl there or you could insert you own UrlGenerator.  Not sure which would be easier in your specific case.  Probably making your own UrlGenerator.