# Strange behaviour in Symfony2 Twig assets with multiple assets_base_urls defined

Tags: symfony, configuration, twig, assets

i'm dealing with some legacy code and a symfony2 app

config.yml:

```
framework:
...
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_base_urls:
      http: [%app.path%, %cdn.path%]
```

app.path: path to legacy assets

cdn.path: path to symfony app assets

```
<img ... src="{{ asset('foto/'~foto.pathB) }}">
<img ... src="{{ asset('foto/'~foto.pathM) }}">
<img ... src="{{ asset('foto/'~foto.pathS) }}">
```

the issue is all about those three imgs, asset() on the first img refer to the second base_url (cdn.path) and the last two to the first one (app.path), seems like not a deterministic behaviour to me though all the assets are on the first base_url, i really can't see why the first asset() jumps to the next base_url

btw i've cleaned my dev cache without success

**UPDATE**

[Solution to multiple cdns!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749088/symfony2-twig-generate-alternate-absolute-url-path-for-use-with-cdn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls):

> If multiple base URLs are provided, Symfony2 will select one from the
>   collection each time it generates an asset's path.

Now if we look at the [corresponding code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/Asset/UrlPackage.php#L66), we have:

```
public function getBaseUrl($path)
    {
        switch ($count = count($this->baseUrls)) {
            case 0:
                return '';

            case 1:
                return $this->baseUrls[0];

            default:
                return $this->baseUrls[fmod(hexdec(substr(md5($path), 0, 10)), $count)];
        }
    }
```

In the case of an array (`default` here), the url taken from the array depends on the `$path` you give as an argument to the function. So one `$path` will always give the same url but all the `$path` don't necessarily give the same url.

Comment: awesome answer, though i'm quite scared about this implementation, are you aware of why it works that way?
i was quite sure the base_urls were iterated from 0 to n-1 until the first valid asset match.
some hint to help me cope with this?

Comment: Well, not sure about the why but one of the reason could be that it is a way to try to generate as much link on each baseUrl you pass as possible (so one don't get all the traffic will the other ones are not doing a thing). But that's just an assumption! :)

Comment: that's a good assumption and i've had the same one, but "load balancing" would be a more clear way to describe than "assets_base_urls" :)
thank you once again