# generating url not based off subdomain's in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have followed the following [tutorial](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains) to handle dynamic subdomains. So say the redirection is successful and I am already at www.subdomain.domain.com. Now when I click on other links in the site it goes to www.subdomain.domain.com/myotherlink, while in fact all of my links should go to www.domain.com/myotherlink. Here's how I generate links in my twig file:

```
{{ path('MyAppMainBundle_marketplace') }}
```

The route in the controller looks something like this:

```
/**
     * @Route("", name="MyAppMainBundle_marketplace", options={"sitemap" = true})
     * @Template("MyAppMainBundle:MarketPlace:index.html.twig")
     */
```

How do I enforce such that all links on my site that is generated using the twig syntax above goes to mydomain.com/myotherlink? I think the issue is I don't want a relative path. I wanted an absolute path? I tried replacing path above with url, however it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more information on exactly what the template you are using is creating the link in question, but I think this other stackoverflow answer might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9750494/1978759

Hope this helps.